# How to interpret coefficients of a GLM (Gamma family with identity link)

Tags: multiple-regression, gamma-distribution, link-function

I'm trying to interpret a coefficient of a glm model with the gamma family and the identity link function. The outcome is continuous, positive and right-skewed. Transformation did not yield a normal distribution.

My model looks like this:
`model_glm_gamma = glm(outcome ~  var1 + var2 + var3, data = data, family = Gamma(link = "identity"))`
`
Coefficients:

|  | Estimate | Std. Error | t value | Pr(>t) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Intercept | 4.91 | 0.58 | 8.4 | <0.0001 |
| Var 1 | -0.81 | 0.21 | - 3.7 | 0.0002 |
| Var2 | -2.16 | 0.74 | - 2.9 | 0.0040 |
| Var3 | -0.33 | 0.57 | - 0.5 | 0.5564 |

How do I interpret the coefficients for var2 if it is -2.16 if var2 is categorical and has two levels 0 and 1.

A coefficient of -2.16 for var2 means that the predicted value of the response variable is expected to be 2.16 units lower for level 1 ocompared to level 0, while holding all other variables constant?

Comment: The identity link is not usually a good choice for a Gamma-family model. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/356053/28500), for example. Your model can in principle lead to predictions of negative values (even if all of your observations are positive), while the Gamma distribution is only defined over positive values. Please edit the question to show the model summary with all of the coefficient estimates, including the intercept.

Comment: Thanks! I have added the coefficients. My idea was that the interpreation of the coefficients would be simpler.